# Sqlite convert text to decimal?

Tags: java, android, sql

I have an Sqlitedb, with a column: `amount text not null`

In column amount, I store dollar values in this format: $1.01, $40.58, etc.

I'm trying to sum up the dollar values using

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM record WHERE date LIKE '"+date+"'"
```

However, it doesn't work, presumably because you can't add text. I know this isn't the ideal storage but how would I go about parsing the amounts so that I can add them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you have stated this is far from the ideal way to store the values (which should be in `decimal` / `real` format from the start), however you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(SUBSTR(amount, 2)) FROM record WHERE date LIKE '"+date+"'"
```

The `SUBSTR` method is a text function that will take a section of the text (in this case, from a starting index). The problem here was the `$` sign, which was confused the dynamic type conversion into believing you were trying to add strings together.

This should now work as SQLLite allows for [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (which in a nutshell, means that the value is used for comparison, not the container).

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to store the amounts as *unscaled* integers, and just format them when needed for display. You get more compact storage, and easier and faster addition. Using integers avoids the risk of rounding errors in floating-point representations.

By *unscaled*, I mean $1.23 would be stored as the integer 123. (Use `long` in your Java code, and `INTEGER` in the SQL.)

You can format amounts for display by querying the locale for the relevant info:

```
// implement this any way you like!
long         amount   = getAmountFromDb();    

// use default locale if you want
Locale       locale       = getLocaleFromSomewhere();                 
Currency     currency     = Currency.getInstance(locale);
NumberFormat format       = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
int          scale        = currency.getDefaultFractionDigits();

BigDecimal   scaledAmount = new BigDecimal(unscaledBalance).movePointLeft(scale);
String       textAmount   = format.format(scaledAmount);
```